# Dependency of HTML rendering on function's return value that executes later?

Tags: php

I have a function that prints "Our data" first and then inside a loop checks for all the data in the database and then prints the data.

However, if there is no data, it shouldn't print "Our data", how do I achieve this since "Our data" is already printed?

The layout is as follows :

```
<h1> Our Data </h1>
<p> <!-- DATA --> </p>
```

The function is as follows:

```
function cpt_info($cpt_slug, $field_name, $title) {
    echo "<h1>Our" . $title . "</h1>"; //here I want to print our data
    $args = array('limit' => -1);
    $cpt = pods($cpt_slug, $args);
    $page_slug = pods_v('last', 'url');
    echo "<h1 class='projects-under-" . $cpt_slug . "'>" . $title . "</h1>";
    if ($cpt->total() > 0) :
        while ($cpt->fetch()) :
            if (!strcasecmp($cpt->field('post_name'), $page_slug)) :
                $data = $cpt->field($field_name);
                foreach ((array) $data as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value != null) : //here I check whether data is empty 
                        $url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($value['ID']));
                        echo "<div class='col-sm-3 col-xs-6'><div class='border-to-circle'>";
                        echo "<div class='circle-container' style='background: url(" . $url . ")center center, url(" . get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/rwp-banner.jpg' . ")center center;'><h4><a href='" . get_permalink($value['ID']) . "'>" . $value['post_title'] . "</a></h4></div>";
                        echo "</div></div>";
                    endif;
                }
            endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Print "Our data" *after* you have queried for and counted the data...!? There's no magic involved, just a simple `if (count($data) > 0)) : ?><h1>Our Data</h1> ...`

Comment: First, count the data and then print the data

Comment: @deceze the process of checking if data exists is itself very complicated, please check the revised question

Comment: You do have an `if ($cpt->total() > 0)` in there already! Just move the output of your headlines **into that `if` statement**.

Comment: Then instead of echoing in the order you are doing now, store the data in a variable and then echo it after you've gathered the data. (At the end).

Comment: @deceze, the `$cpt->total()` can be non-empty and yet the `$value` can be `null`. Whether the title should appear or not completely depends on whether `$value` is `null` or not

Comment: Then indeed: put the data into an array in your loop and check afterwards if you have any data in your array, then go about outputting it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
if(count($data)){
  echo '<h1> Our Data </h1>';
}
```